# Each or plural noun?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, vocabulary, structure

Well, I am confused about the directions I should give to the test section with the following characteristics:

There are ten situations that can be represented by proverbs on the question-sheet. The students are to write the proverbs. One situation needs one proverb only. Which instruction is the best:

1. Write a proverb for each situation.
2. Write a proverb representing each situation.
3. Write proverbs representing each situation.
4. Write proverbs representing the situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

> Write a **separate** proverb for each situation.

Alternatively, something like this might work:

> Write proverbs **unique** to each situation.

You could write something twice as long that would make the meaning even more explicit—but you need to accept a reasonable trade-off between simplicity and deliberate misunderstanding. In other words, there's always some way of forcing an incorrect meaning onto something—but it become impractical to guard against it beyond a certain point. (It would take convoluted reasoning to be able to make the above two sentences mean something different than what you're looking for.)

Comment: What if we simply say "write a proverb for each situation" ?

Comment: @FadliSheikh I assumed you didn't like that version, because it was capable of being misunderstood. In theory, it could mean the following *Write a [**single**] proverb [**that can be used**] for each situation.* You could end up with one proverb that applies to 10 different situations, rather than 10 different proverbs, one for each.

Comment: you are right. I thought like that. But, since such a phrase is commonly used to say so among non-natives (at least, Indonesians), I am sure they won't misunderstand it. Nevertheless, your versions are also great. Thanks, Bassford.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to be clear in what you are asking for, so I would use the slightly wordier:

> For each of these situations, write a proverb that represents that situation.

It's a bit longer but I feel it is clearer that the proverbs whould be specific to one situation, and each situation should have one proverb.

Comment: But, it sounds a bit tautological, Rob. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: You could reduce it to "For each of these situations, write a proverb that represents it" I delibertely chose to add in 'that situation' as you stated this is an assessment question and it is helpful to students that the question cannot be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Both Rob Lamden's and Jason Bassford's suggestions are good. Nevertheless, I think they can be improved.

Neither suggestion appears to recognize that the choice of proverb is restricted to those supplied. Now I concede that the restriction may be implied, but my experience is that trusting people to recognize the implicit is foolish, to say the least. So my suggestion is:

> Select, from the ten proverbs provided, the one most appropriate to each described situation without selecting one more than once.

In other words, you are asking for a one-to-one correspondance and expecting the application of understanding and **judgment** to making the correspondences.

Comment: Look, I believe there's a misunderstanding. The proverbs are not on the sheet to be matched to the situations. The students have to try to remember the suitable proverbs all by themselves.

Comment: "proverbs on the question sheet" is unambiguous. However, if the students are to select from the proverbs previously taught, the adjustment needed is obvious.

Comment: they are asked to write proverbs representing the situations. They have got all the proverbs. So, basically, they should think of the proverbs they have got and choose the relevant proverbs.